# How to test with @JSONManagedReference the way I want it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want to show the "parent" data in the "child" entity response in a `@manyToOne` relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @JsonBackReference(value = "parent-children")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", targetEntity = Child.class)
    private List<Children> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "parent-children")
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
}
```

The response object for such a relationship is amazing, exactly what I want

```
GET web.site/children/all

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parent": {
      "id": 1,
      "other": "data",
    },
  }
]
```

But when I run tests, the test runner can't compile! Searching for this error on Google gets me to several articles that say that I have the relationship the wrong way around.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'parent-children': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (website.entities.Child)
```

Switching the types around causes JSON results I don't want

```
GET web.site/children/all

[
  {
    "id": 1,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("parent")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", targetEntity = Child.class)
    private List<Children> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("children")    
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
}
```

**Some notes**:

1) You are using `mappedBy="account"`, why don't you use `mappedBy="parent"` ?

2) By convention, you should use `private List<Children> childrens;` in plural